# Newtonsoft.Json replacing spaces with underscores C# to JSON Serialize

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

INITIAL QUESTION:

Here I have a function I use to convert from Entity Framework object to JSON:

```
public class JSON
{
    public static string ConvertEntityToJSON(object dataToSerialize)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSerialize,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
    }
}
```

When debugging, "dataToSerialize" looks like following:

```
SELECT 
[xxx].[Firstattributefromdatabase] AS [First attribute from database], 
[xxx].[Secondattributefromdatabase] AS [Second attribute from database]
FROM [xxx]
```

So as visible, there are spaces between words in the attribute names from SQL, not underscores, but the output (for one row in table) looks like following:

```
[{"First_attribute_from_database":"xxx","Second_attribute_from_database":"xxx"}]
```

Any clues for what might be causing this and how can this be fixed? I am loading this JSON data in a pivot table, which results in all fields having underscores instead of spaces between words.

---

UPDATE 1:

Okay, so after looking into what was generated from database using Entity Framework (EF designer from database; database-first approach), the class that was generated was the following:

```
public partial class TestClass
{
    public string First_attribute_from_database { get; set; }
    public string Second_attribute_from_database { get; set; }
}
```

Even though it was explicitly defined in the MS SQL Server Management Studio that this is a VIEW (not a table itself) and the SQL is formatted as following:

```
SELECT 
[xxx].[Firstattributefromdatabase] AS [First attribute from database], 
[xxx].[Secondattributefromdatabase] AS [Second attribute from database]
FROM [xxx]
```

So here the question arises: How to overcome a problem of underlines as C# properties can't have spaces in their names?

Comment: That dataToSerialize "format" does not make sense. What is the actual type behind dataToSerialize?

Comment: the select is the query from your EF, please show us your entity

Comment: Just posted an "update 1" where the generated class from database is

Comment: You can't have spaces in identifiers in C#. Your C# Properties will either have to have underscores or some other legal character there or you remove it, so that it would be `FirstAttributeFromDatabase`.

Comment: Can I keep underscores in C# properties and somehow later when JSON string is generated change underscores in only JSON properties and not the JSON data?

Comment: Try tagging those properties with `[JsonProperty("a b c")]`

Comment: Tagging them manually would result in a disaster, as our database model is updated almost on a daily basis and we manually force updating the C# model from database every 2-3 days. I posted a simplified version of the class in order to simplify this for everyone who can help, but there are thousands of properties and manually adding [JsonProperty("a b c")] to each of them is not a solution in this case, even though it would work remarkably if not having database-first approach and database to model generation

Comment: You could use a `NamingStrategy` as shown in [How to apply a general rule for remapping all property names when serializing with Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46476903/3744182).  In fact, is this a duplicate?

Comment: @dbc thanks for another useful article. While the very “idea” of a solution is the same, the approach to execute the solution is different if I understand correctly. Also, I was trying to replace underscore, so if anyone else is trying the same thing, they will never find (same as I didn’t) the article you pointed, as there is no word about underscores, but only “removing spaces”, so I at least hope it might help someone else regarding the same issue as I had, as luckily I have come up to a simple and effective solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Found [this wonderful article](https://migara.li/2016/01/09/json-net-easy-serialization/) in the meantime. Upon that I just implemented functions from the article, modified Replace in ResolvePropertyName and voila, my code is working splendidly! Hope this helps everyone else who is using Entity Framework, generating model from database and trying to go from C# objects to JSON.

```
public class JSON
{
    public static string ConvertEntityToJSON(object dataToSerialize)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSerialize,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
    }
}

public class UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(propertyName, "_", " ");
    }
}
```