# JSON.Net - Deserialisation - underscore in property value turns into space

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a POCO object like this -

```
class User
{
     string FullName { get; set;}
     DateTime DOJ { get; set;}
     string UserName { get; set;}
}
```

I have a WebAPI that sends following JSON to update user

```
PUT /user/{user-id}
{
    "FullName ": "My Name",
    "DOJ": "01-05-2018",
    "UserName": "My_user_Name"
}

// Deserialize in C# code
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Above-Json-String);
```

When i deserialize this json using JSON.net apis, value for "user.UserName" is "My user Name", the underscores got converted into space.

Any solution to preserve underscores in the property value?

Comment: I just tried deserializing from a string constant and the underscores were preserved. So I don't think it's the deserialization that does it. Could it be something in the transport layer that changes them to spaces? Quick test: See if your JSON string has the underscores before deserialization.

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589794/newtonsoft-json-replacing-spaces-with-underscores-c-sharp-to-json-serialize)

Comment: @sunrise: That's in the property *name*, not the *value*.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948266/c-sharp-json-to-array-debugging-application-went-to-break-mode/47948781#47948781 will help you

Comment: @Hans  - Thanks for your reply.
I tried your test and i can see underscores before deserialization. So its passing through transport layer.
BTW, what version of library are you using?  i am using "8.0.3.19514" and i cant change to higher versions because of business reasons.

Comment: @smhetre I'm using 10.0.3 and the code I used is var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>("{\"FullName\": \"My Name\", \"DOJ\": \"01-05-2018\", \"UserName\": \"My_user_Name\"}");

Comment: I just tried with 8.0.3 and that works for me as well... Strange...

Answer (score 3):

Jsonproperty might solve your issue stated.

Use the JsonProperty attribute to indicate the name in the JSON.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "binding type")]
string FullName { get; set;}
```