# JsonMediaTypeFormatter not formatting data correclty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, formatter, camelcasing

I am using following code in ASP.NET Web API application.

```
  //Support camel casing
            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

When returning JSON via POCO or DataTable, it converts property name in camel casing.

Assume  My class has two properties.

```
Class Obj{
        public string DataBase{ get; set; }
        public string ChangedBy { get; set; }

}
```

When I return any object of this class, I will get JSON like this:

```
{   
   "dataBase":"Oracle",
   "changedBy":"XYZ"
}
```

It seems issue is when you have '_' in the property name. CamelCasing is not making sense.

My class has columns like this:

```
DATA_BASE 
CHANGED_BY
```

Now, I am receiving JSON like this:

```
 {   
   "datA_BASE":"Oracle",
   "changeD_BY":"XYZ"
}
```

I was expecting:

```
 {   
       "dATA_BASE":"Oracle",
       "cHANGED_BY":"XYZ"
    }
```

Comment: Hello! This seems too unclear. How is your DataTable sending you two values at the same time?

Comment: @MilkyWay90: Let me update my question. I do not follow you fully. My DataTable has multiple columns.

Comment: You say it is sending you "DATA_BASE" and "datA_BASE"

Comment: @MilkyWay90: I updated the question. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Okay; it makes sense now.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374261/issue-with-default-camelcase-serialization-of-all-caps-property-names-to-json-in/52375107#52375107 Full caps names with underscore have the same result.